# How to count xml element value?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

My source XML is below, out from it, I want to count the XML element value.
For example, XML element I want to know `url1` value i.e.

1. How many False URL1 are present in the code? In this case it is 3.

I am applying `count(/report_data/report_entry/url1)`, but, how to know the value of `url1`?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<report_data>
    <report_entry>
        <url1>true</url1>
        <url2>100</url2>
    </report_entry>
    <report_entry>
        <url1>false</url1>
        <url2>200</url2>
    </report_entry>
    <report_entry>
        <url1>true</url1>
        <url2>150</url2>
    </report_entry>
    <report_entry>
        <url1>false</url1>
        <url2>150</url2>
    </report_entry>
    <report_entry>
        <url1>false</url1>
        <url2>150</url2>
    </report_entry>
</report_data>
```

Comment: I think you need `count(/report_data/report_entry/url1[. = 'false'])`.

Comment: I just tried but it's still not working . It just returning blank data

Comment: I think something else must be wrong for you, as the expression should work. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBt1.